# Can't find BroadCom BLE SDK

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

After reading many posts, i figured out that [Broadcom SDK](http://code.google.com/p/broadcom-ble/) was missing into my projects while i was trying to run my BLE sample projects but when i try to reach this link, Google tell me that this link was not found :

"404. That’s an error.
The requested URL /p/broadcom-ble/ was not found on this server. That’s all we know."

Could someone tell me please how i can run my BLE sample code or where i can find this SDK?
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

It appears the api you want doesn't exist on the internet anymore. Not even in archives of the internet (the archive machines with the correct file are apparently down.)

But, I found this for you:

https://code.google.com/r/naranjomanuel-opensource-broadcom-ble/

See if that's something you can use. It appears similar.

Comment: This is where i found my sample code but he uses this .jar I didn't found yet =/

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20130408105433/http://broadcom-ble.googlecode.com/files/OpenBleApi_r05.zip

The machine that serves this is currently down, but maybe if they bring it back up it'll exist. The repository.xml existed and I downloaded that!

Comment: And, honestly, the link I gave you in my answer doesn't use a jar because it looks like it's all written from scratch. It looks like, in the git repository, the actual sources for the library are there. So now you can compile it into an SO and the sources for the jar are sure to be there as well.

Answer (score 0):

HTC BLE SDK is mainly based on Broadcom's SDK. Some classes might be different, but you can try to make it work... You would need an HTC device though...You can try and see if there is BLE support from other manufacturers as far as SDK (I think Samsung also has a BLE SDK)

You can also try to wait until the new release for Android comes around, it will support BLE